# Play! framework template engine form, how to show custom error messages

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm using play! framework with scala to deploy a web application.
I would like to open a popup message when an User fail to login.

This is my scala template code:

```
@form(routes.Application.login) {
            <div class="emailaddress">E-mail address:</div>
            <div class="inputbox">
                @helper.input(userForm("email"), '_id -> "email", '_label->"" ) { (id, name, value, args) => 
                            <input placeholder="Insert email" type="text" class="email-input" id="@id" name="@name" value="" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
                        }

            </div>
            <div class="password">Password:</div>
            <div class="inputbox1">
                @helper.input(userForm("password"), '_id -> "password", '_label->"") { (id, name, value, args) => 
                            <input placeholder="Insert password" class="password-input" type="password" id="@id" name="@name" value="" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
                        }
            </div>
            <div >
                <button id="submit-button" class="myButton" >Submit</button>
            </div>
            @if(userForm.hasGlobalErrors) { 
                    <div class="alert alert-error">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
          function to javascriptPopUp(@userForm.globalError.get.message);
                    </div>
            }
        }
```

and my controller code is :

```
def login = Action { implicit request => 
    userForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        errors=> BadRequest(views.html.user.userLogin(UserDB.findAll, errors)),
        user => {
                val use = UserDB.findUserByLogin(user.email, user.password)
                if(use!=None){
                    Redirect(routes.DataManagementController.projects).withSession(Security.username -> user.email).flashing("success" -> "You've been logged in")
                }else{
                    Ok(views.html.user.userLogin(UserDB.findAll, userForm))
                }

        }
    ) 
}
```

But even with error it never gets to my javascript function. 
Can anybody explain to me why I never get in?

(if you need more code, ask and I will post it, I'm just saving space on this page because Login works, I can't just show message errors).

Comment: What is UserDB.findAll?  Is that the form you are passing to the login view?

Comment: Also can you post the form code in the controller where you do the validation?

Comment: If you paste the following on your page, do you get back validation errors?

    `@if(userForm.hasErrors) {
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            @if(userForm.errors.size() > 0) {
                @for((key, value) <- userForm.errors) {
                    @key.toString() :
                    @for(err <- value) {
                        @err.message()
                    }
                }
            } else {No error returned.}
        </div>
    }`